# Where are ArcGIS Toolbox results saved?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, log, results-window

I need to copy the warning messages which are logged in the ArcToolbox geoprocessing results. The message contains warnings which I need to work through at a later date. Unfortunately, I am not able to copy the warnings in the results windows in ArcMap or ArcCatalog. The XML log file for the Toolbox only contains the parameters.

Is there a way to access these messages?

Comment: Using thd result() function in arcpy may be helpful. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm#C_GUID-79775729-7D10-4576-A629-18F74EC88F16

Answer (score 4):

If you go to the results window after a tool has run, expand the tool then right click on Messages and Copy.

[image: Messages]

This works well for the odd tool but not for capturing messages from hundreds of tools. You might find the Help on [Viewing tool execution history](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm) informative.